# How to configure formly custom components inside standalone components in angular 16

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

Angular Version: 16.0.4
Formly Version: 6.1.7

I just changed my Angular project to standalone components, which deleted all of the modules.
We developed custom formly components, such as input fields and dropdown menus, with the following configuration:

```
 @NgModule({
  FormlyModule.forRoot({
      types: [
        {
          name: 'input',
          component: CustomInputComponent,
          wrappers: ['test-wrapper'],
        }
      ],
      validators: [
        {
          name: 'mandatory',
          validation: CustomMandatoryValidator,
        },
      ],
      wrappers: [
        {
          name: 'test-wrapper',
          component: TestWrapperComponent,
        },
      ],
    })
  })
```

It's generating an issue when I try to relocate this configuration inside the standalone components imports section.
**Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[] | Type'**, How to fix this issue

Answer (score 3):

Define the FormlyModule in main.ts and import into the standalone-component.

main.ts

```html
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        importProvidersFrom([
            FormlyModule.forRoot({
                validationMessages: [{ name: 'required', message: 'This field is required' }],
                types: [
                  { name: 'object', component: ObjectTypeComponent },
                ],
              }),
        ]),
...
```

Component.ts

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'formly-object-type',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormlyModule, CommonModule],
  ...
```

Comment: Hello, I'm using an starter example, very simple, but I give this error only with standalone components, please help me.
core.mjs:10194 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: To add to this, formly adds quite a bit to the bundle size, you can include the providers on the routes that need it only, rather than the bootstrap if thats good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here is what worked for me: I provided `FORMLY_CONFIG` in the main `AppModule` and imported `FormlyModule` in the standalone component:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ]
  providers: [
    {
      provide: FORMLY_CONFIG,
      multi: true,
      useValue: {
        types: [
          { name: 'datetime', component: DatetimePickerComponent, wrappers: ['form-field'] },
          { name: 'color', component: ColorPickerComponent, wrappers: ['form-field'] },
        ],
      }
    },
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And standalone component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-standalone',
  templateUrl: './standalone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./standalone.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormlyModule,
    FormlyBootstrapModule,
  ],
})
export class StandaloneComponent {}
```